# spliting git repository from eclipse project - egit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I'm more or less a git newbie, trying to get a good Setup to work in Eclipse with egit. I'm running Kepler with latest updates.

Originally I Setup the structure inside the Workspace Directory.

```
+Workspace/.git
+Workspace/TheProject
```

Using this Setup (admittedly with Juno) commits were taking forever. For this and other reasons I'd like to move git outside the Workspace Directory, outside eclipse in a parallel Directory.

```
+OtherDirectory/.git
+Workspace/TheProject
```

But I'm not getting very far. There seems to be no easy way to split the EXISTING git to another Location without having the Project move there too(!?)

I've tried e.g. Cloning the existing git (in the git repository perspective) and having it Import the Project in the same move.
I've tried just Cloning the existing git, without selection of "Import Project" at the same time.
Then I right clicked the cloned repository and went through the Import Existing Project dialog. I don't get a Chance to say where the Project should be loaded to.

In both cases the Project Ends up in the same Directory as the .git Directory (now outside the Workspace)

```
+OtherDirectory/.git
+OtherDirectory/TheProject
```

and not as I wish - to have the Project in the Workspace Directory.

This must be possible (?), but how?

Answer (score -1):

Simply copy the `.classpath` and `.project` from `Workspace/TheProject` or `OtherDirectory/TheProject`, to `otherDirectory` (where the `.git` folder is).

Then import your project into the workspace, as in "[Eclipse - Import an existing project?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18605958/6309)"

Everything will remain in `OtherDirectory/` (outside your Eclipse workspace folder), but will be visible in your Eclipse workspace.

Comment: Sorry from where should I copy `.classpath` and `.Project` FROM? I copy these TO `OtherDirectory`? And when you say "Everything will remain in `OtherDirectory`" - do you mean git or the Eclipse Project files `TheProject`... or both?

Comment: @JamesCook from `Workspace/TheProject` or `OtherDirectory/TheProject`, where Eclipse must have created them.

Comment: I've tried this twice now. Just to restate - I'm seeking to SPLIT git Location from the Project Location. I don't want everything under the same Directory.

    +OtherDirectory/.git
    +Workspace/TheProject

Importing the Project as you indicate leaves the .git and prject directories in `OtherDirectory` (if I don't select to copy the files to the Workspace) or in `Workspace^ if I do

Comment: DId you try a File → Import → Git → Projects from Git, as I mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/6760785/6309

Comment: @JamesCook otherwise, I like to have the `.project` and `.classpath` in the same folder as the sources, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/337317/6309. That is, assuming the `.classpath` onlyrefers to relative paths, like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/300346/6309.