# Re-install Eclipse with existing source code

Tags: eclipse

I accidentally uninstall my Eclipse App, and after I reinstall it the workplace is blank.
However, I still have all my source code in a different folder.

Any idea on how to get my code working in the App again, like sync the folder into the workplace maybe?

Big thanks!

Comment: Probably it opened a new workspace. Try switching back to older workspace.File -> Switch Workspace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse - Import an existing project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459395/eclipse-import-an-existing-project)

Answer (score 0):

Go to

File --> Open Projects from File System --> and Select the folder in which all of your eclipse projects are located in --> Select All --> Finish